# error bernstein vandermonde julia.

Tags: julia

the following error occurs. I tried to change the n .... but not working
"LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 9-element Array{Float64,1}:"

```
function bernstein_vandermonde( n )

  if n == 1
    v = ones(1, 1);
  return v
  end

  v = zeros( n, n );
  x = linspace( 0, 1, n );
  for i = 1:n
    println("entra no loop")
    v[i,1:n] = bernstein_poly_01(n - 1, x[i])
  end

  return v

  end

function bernstein_poly_01( n, x )
   bern = ones(n)
   if n == 0
    bern[1] = 1

    elseif 0 < n 
    bern[1] = 1 -x
    bern[2] = x

        for i = 2:n
            bern[i+1] = x*bern[i];

            for j = i-1:-1: 1
                bern[j+1] = x*bern[j] + (1 - x)*bern[j+1]
            end

            bern[1] = (1 - x)*bern[1]
        end

    end 
    return bern
end
```

I can not solve :(

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do here, but your error is happening on the line `bern[i+1] = x*bern[i]` when `i=n` as `bern` has length `n` and you are trying to assign the `n+1` element.

Comment: strange when I make the conversion to matlab, wheel well.

Comment: If you access an array at a position that does not currently exist, Julia gives an error,  but matlab automatically increases the size of the array to the necessary length.

Comment: Thanks Sanders, in fact is this that occur, matlab is optimized for solved this problem.